# how to write a code that loops more than once using the for loop function in python

Tags: python

here is my code:

```py
number = input("How many students are registering?")

for i in number:
    id_number = input("Enter your ID Number:")
    print(id_number)

with open("reg_form.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(id_number+"\n")
```

the code has to loop for the same number entered in variable "number" in my code above.

Comment: what is wrong with this? what problem yoiu are getting and trying to achive, you need to use `for i in range(int(number))`

Comment: you need to case `number` to an `int` otherwise you are just iterating over the characters in the given value: `number = int(input("How many students are registering?"))`. Keep in mind you will need to handle the case where the users doesn't enter a valid number

Comment: the value that is passed to number variable is a string because that is how input() works. you have to convert it to int like int(input("how many students are registering?"))

Answer (score 1):

this question shows no research effort, but here is what you are looking for:

```py
with open("reg_form.txt","w") as f:
    for i in range(int(input('how many students registering?'))):
        id_number = input("Enter your ID Number:")
        print(id_number)
        f.write(id_number+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick (making sure the input is an integer & you iterate over an iterable (range))

```
number = int(input("How many students are registering?"))

for i in range(number):
    id_number = input("Enter your ID Number:")
    print(id_number)
```

Comment: you forgot the file writing.

Comment: agreed, I am not exactly sure what the second half really is supposed to do. maybe @Ophethile will clarify that later and then I will revisit my answer.

Comment: they clearly want to write/append each `id_number` to an output file in each iteration of the loop. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use a For Loop with *number*.

Here's the code:

```
number = input("How many students are registering?")

for i in range(int(number)):
  id_number = input("Enter your ID Number:")
  print(id_number)

  with open("reg_form.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(id_number+"\n")
```

I believe you meant to put the With Statement within the For Loop, because it won't work otherwise (id_number isn't defined).

Comment: by putting the `with` statement inside of the `for` loop you are creating a lot of overhead with open/close operations whereas we could open file one time then loop through the input values to write to it in each step of the loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what is your problem, but I think i can help you

```
number = input("How many students are registring")
for i in range(1,int(number))
   id_number = input("Enter your ID Number: ")
   print(id_number)
 with open("reg_form.txt","w") as f: f.write(id_number+"\n")
```

Comment: Your code won't work because you need to use an integer when using a range.